# Creating strings from dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

My dataframe

```
x1 <- data.frame(C1 = letters[1:4], C3=1:4, C3=letters[11:14])
```

I need something a list where each listelement are two values from a row

```
x2 <- list(c("a", "1"), c("b", "2"), c("c", "3"), c("d", "4"))
```

Basically each two values from a row need to be a listelement so that I can process them later on!

I tried

```
lapply(X = x2, MARGIN = 1, FUN = paste, collapse = "")
```

But that did not give me the desired output!

Comment: `split(as.matrix(x1[,1:2]), seq_len(nrow(x1)))` I guess. Sort of a weird operation to do, though.

Comment: @Frank Why is it a weird operation? Your code gives me `[1] "b" "2"`. I need `[1] "b2"`

Comment: Hm, now I'm really confused because your question actually says "I need something [...] `c("b", "2")`" presumably describing desired output. Anyways, it is a weird operation to (i) use numbers stored as strings and (ii) to split a data.frame by rows. Generally, such steps are not necessary in R.

Comment: @Frank I should have phrased that differently! Depending what you do I guess ;) I need it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
paste0(x1[,1], x1[,2])
# [1] "a1" "b2" "c3" "d4"
```

How about:

```
as.list(paste0(x1[,1], x1[,2]))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a1"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "b2"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "c3"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "d4"
```

It doesn't matter how many rows you have. You just need to specify the columns you want pasted into a string.

Comment: Nearly. I need it in a list. I also do not know how big my dataframe is. Maybe it has 1000 rows, maybe just 2. I only know which colums I want to transform!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using lapply:

```
lapply(1:nrow(x1), function(i) c(x1[i,1], x1[i,2]))
```

The result is

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "1"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "2"

[[3]]
[1] "c" "3"

[[4]]
[1] "d" "4"
```

**data**

```
x1 <- data.frame(C1 = letters[1:4], C3=1:4, C3=letters[11:14],
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Note that I used the stringsAsFactors = F argument to construct the data. If I didn't do this, then C1 and C3 would be factors, so I'd have to wrap `x[i, 1]` in `as.character`.

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple columns, we can use `do.call`

```
as.list(do.call(paste0, x1[-3]))
```

Comment: FWIW, this wasn't meant as snark. I'm just asking about the value add of `do.call`.

Comment: @gung Thanks for the reply.  I misunderstood your comment.  Sorry